# How can i prevent onclick button from multiple click until it's confirmation from javascript if(confirm ) condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="button" onclick="return saveValues();" value="<?php echo "values" ?>" class="silver_button_big">
```

On the above to stop the multiclick i have tried something like this.

```
my_toggle_var = 0; // your global variable which u can use to play 
function saveValues() {

if (my_toggle_var  == 0)
{
    ic.do.something();
    my_toggle_var  = 1; // You can move it up down based on your need....
}
},

 something : function(){
  //some code
  //these code lead to run some jar file
  // data insertion into DB(using mysql)

}
```

But this is unable to solve my problem in above case, i can say there may be some sort of browser cache problem.
Can somebody help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `disabled="disabled"` and `readonly="readonly"` attributes:

```js
// Attach the click handler
$(".silver_button_big").on("click", function() {

  var $this = $(this);

  // Disable button
  $this.attr({"disabled": "disabled", "readonly": "readonly"});

  // Do something async
  setTimeout(function() {
    
    // Enable the button back
    $this.removeAttr("disabled readonly");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click me" class="silver_button_big">
```

Note that it's recommended [not to use empty attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values).

Comment: u also can add to disabled the readonly attr, too. some mobile devices or no-name browsers ignoring disabled when its standalone

Comment: i know its solved but one last thing: in W3C a "non-filled-attr" is not recommended cause nothing is settet and it can happen that the browser or device ignore this too, u can solve this by simply add disabled and readonly to itself: `readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"`, in jq-js its `$.attr({"disabled":"disabled","readonly":"readonly"})` -- @IonicăBizău ur welcome :)

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Good point, thanks! Can you provide the reference?

Comment: have a look at [W3C html restrictions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values), in this (and other) sections u will find many hints  about that

Answer (score 0):

```
my_toggle_var = 0; // your global variable which u can use to play 
function saveValues() {

if (my_toggle_var  == 0)
{
    my_toggle_var  = 1; // You can move it up down based on your need....
    ic.do.something();
}
}

 something : function(){
  //some code
  //these code lead to run some jar file
  // data insertion into DB(using mysql)

}
```